SPI communication, clock abnormal later than CS？
I use A40i and STM32 for SPI communication. A40i is an ARMv7 architecture processor, running on a Linux system in my environment. A40i is the SPI host and STM32 is the SPI slave. For the sake of convenience, I have attached a screenshot of the oscilloscope when there is an abnormality. The process of my program is that when I read IRQ, I perform SPI communication (fixed 300 bytes, baud rate is 10 M). IRQ is generated by the GPIO connected to STM32 outside of SPI, and STM32 generates IRQ every 8 ms. Under normal circumstances, after receiving IRQ, A40i will immediately initiate SPI communication, and SPI communication will also be executed quickly. However, after running the program for several hours, the situation shown in the screenshot will appear. IRQ is generated as expected, and CS signal is also lowered as expected. However, CLK is 9.8 ms late, causing the next process to be affected. What are the possibilities of this?


Under the same conditions, I also caught this situation. The data has been sent, but the chip select has not been raised yet.


Your Linux system is busy doing something else and can't start SPI until too late. Are you running a real-time Linux?

@Justme Yes, my Linux system has added an RT patch to run the codesys runtime.

@Justme Excuse me, why are you asking if i am using real-time Linux? I hope to receive your guidance, thank you.

Generally Linux isn't real time so it may be busy doing something else than handling your interrupt within a hard real time limit. And even if you are running a real time Linux, you need to figure out why it didn't. Maybe there are other SPI transactions going on.

@Justme I believe this issue is not related to the hardware, right? The most likely cause is a problem with the A40i's SPI driver code? At present, I have tried to isolate the core and thread binding, set the priority of application layer threads, but none of these solutions have worked. I am at a loss and have no clue.

@Justme In the second case, the data has been sent, but the chip select has not been raised yet. Is it a CPU scheduling problem?
